# Access the last value of a variable declared and set in function 1 from function 2 without calling function 1 again

Tags: python, function, variables

I'm trying to understand best practice for accessing the value of variables created/declared in one function from other functions.

I'm using Jupyter notebook and have Python 3.9.13 installed.

My first post here, I'm new to Python, I haven't done any other coding since ActionScript 2.0! and I'm not seeing answers to this question that I understand from my research so far.

So far I have...

```
def func1():
    
    my_var1 = (1 + 1) #...or something that sets a 'value' for this variable
    my_var2 = (2 + 2) #...or something that sets a 'value' for this variable
    
    return my_var1, my_var2

func1() #calls func1
```

```
def func2():
    
    my_var1, my_var2 = func1()
    
    my_var3 = (my_var1 + 1)
    my_var4 = (my_var2 + 1)
    
    return my_var3, my_var4

func2() #calls func1 (and func2 ?)
```

The code above seems to work by calling func1() from within func2() (?) - which works for certain requirements but if I want to get the value of e.g. my_var1 from the last time func1() was called without calling func1() again - I hit problems.

This works so far (I think!)...

```
def func3():
    
    global my_var5
    global my_var6
    
    my_var5 = (1 + 1) #...or something that sets a 'value' for this variable
    my_var6 = (2 + 2) #...or something that sets a 'value' for this variable
    
    return my_var5, my_var6

func3() #calls func3
```

```
def func4():
    
    my_var7 = (my_var5 + 1) #...or something that sets a 'value' for this variable
    my_var8 = (my_var6 + 2) #...or something that sets a 'value' for this variable
    
    return my_var7, my_var8

func4() #calls func4
```

...but most of what I've read has advised against using global although I'm not really understanding those concerns either.

I'd appreciate some insight on this - thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want my_var1 and my_var2 not to be recomputed each time you call func2, why not set them OUTSIDE func2 and use them inside ?

Comment: @Swifty in this example my_var1 and my_var2 are set inside func1 - which is where they need to be. I have an option for getting their values from func2 that involves calling func1 again (the first 2 code snippets) but I'm struggling with an option that doesn't involve calling func1 again (the last 2 code snippets). I need an option that gets me the value of my_var1 and my_var2 from the last time that function was called without calling it again. Thanks.

Comment: That's what I said: remove the statement `my_var1, my_var2 = func1()` from func2 and place it outside. Then you'll be able to access the 2 vars as many times as you want without calling func1 again.

Comment: @Swifty Edit: Unfortunately this isn't looking like a solution for me.

If I remove the statement `my_var1, my_var2 = func1()` from inside func2() and e.g. put it in its own cell in Jupyter, then update the values of my_var1, my_var2 by calling func1() - I don't get those updated values when I run func()2 without first running `my_var1, my_var2 = func1()` and then running func2() again.

So that looks like its doing the same thing as it was when it was inside func2().

Comment: You could use a mutable collection to store your vars: myvars = [0,0] ; then def func1(myvars), and inside func1 put your values into myvars[0] and myvars[1]; this will act just as if you had declared global vars. Yet another way would be for your func1 to return a closure that yields your 2 values when called.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, using a list as 'global' variable:

```
my_vars= [0,0]

def function1(my_vars):
    my_vars[0] = 1
    my_vars[1] = 2

function1(my_vars)
my_vars
# [1,2]
```

Another way, using a closure:

```
def func1():
    def myvars():
        return 1,2
    return myvars

mv = func1()
mv()
# (1, 2)
```